# Does the MMU mediate everything between the operating system and physical memory or is it just an address translator?

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory

I'm trying to understand how does an operating system work when we want to assign some value to a particular virtual memory address.

My first question concerns whether the MMU handles everything between the CPU and the RAM. Is this true? From what one can read from Wikipedia, I'd say so:

> A memory management unit (MMU), sometimes called paged memory
>   management unit (PMMU), is a computer
>   hardware component responsible for
>   handling accesses to memory requested
>   by the CPU.

If that is the case, how can one tell the MMU I want to get 8 bytes, 64 or 128bytes, for example? What about writing?

If that is not the case, I'm guessing the MMU just translates virtual addresses to physical ones?

What happens when the MMU detects there will be what we call a page-fault? I guess it has to tell it to the CPU so the CPU loads the page itself off disk, or is the MMU able to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please read that wikipedia entry further: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit#How_it_works A fair description of what MMU is capable of and how is it controlled via the page table is presented. Then several specific architectures are described.

Comment: That article says nothing about what is happening when I try to set someAddress = 10, for example, nor how are pages loaded in memory..

Comment: A memory controller does the actual transfers.  An MMU would just translate addresses, but what almost all modern processor architectures use is a "memory protection unit" (MPU) which is an enhanced MMU that also limits read, write, or execute access based on flags stored in the page table.

Comment: Although not very related, interested parties can take a look [here.](https://youtu.be/7aONIVSXiJ8)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Devoured Elysium,

I'll attempt to answer your questions one by one but note, it might be a good idea to get your hands on a textbook for an OS course or an introductory computer architecture course.

The MMU consists of some hardware logic and state whose purpose is, indeed, to produce a physical address and provide/receive data to and from the memory controller. Actually, the job of memory translation is one that is taken care of by cooperating hardware and software (OS) mechanisms (at least in modern PCs). Once the physical address is obtained, the CPU has essentially done its job and now sends the address out on a bus which is at some point connected to the actual memory chips. In many systems this bus is called the Front-Side Bus (FSB), which is in turn connected to a memory controller. This controller takes the physical address supplied by the CPU and uses it to interact with the DRAM chips, and ultimately extract the bits in the correct rows and columns of the memory array. The data is then sent back to the CPU, which can now operate on it. Note that I'm not including caching in this description.

So no, the MMU does not interact directly with RAM, which I assume you are using to mean the physical DRAM chips. And you cannot tell the MMU that you want 8 bytes, or 24 bytes, or whatever, you can only supply it with an address. How many bytes that gets you depends on the machine you're on and whether it's byte-addressable or word-addressable.

Your last question urges me to remind you: the MMU is actually a part of the CPU--it sits on the same silicon die (although this was not always the case).

Now, let's take your example with the page fault. Suppose our user-level application wants to, like you said, set someAddress = 10, I'll take it in steps. Let's assume someAddress is 0xDEADBEEF and let's ignore caches for now.

1) The application issues a store instruction to 0xsomeAddress, which, in x86 might look something like

```
mov %eax, 0xDEADBEEF
```

where 10 is the value in the eax register.

2) 0xDEADBEEF in this case is a virtual address, which must be translated. Most of the time, the virtual to physical address translation will be available in a hardware structure called the Translation Lookaside Buffer (TLB), which will provide this translation to us very fast. Typically, it can do so in one clock cycle. If the translation is in the TLB, called a TLB hit, execution can continue immediately (i.e. the physical address corresponding to 0xDEADBEEF and the value 10 are sent out to the memory controller to be written).

3) Let's suppose though, that the translation wasn't available in the TLB (called a TLB miss). Then we must find the translation in the page tables, which are structures in memory whose structure is defined by the hardware and managed by the OS. They simply contain entries that map a virtual address to a physical one (more accurately, a virtual page number to a physical page number). But these structures also reside in memory, and so must have addresses! The hardware contains a special register called cr3 which contains the physical address of the current page table. We can index into this page table using our virtual address, so the hardware takes the value in cr3, computes an address by adding an offset, and goes off to memory to fetch the page table entry (PTE). This PTE will (hopefully) contain the physical address corresponding to 0xDEADBEEF, in which case we put this mapping in the TLB (so we don't have to walk the page table again) and continue on our way.

4) But oh no! What if there is no PTE in the page tables for 0xDEADBEEF? This is a page fault, and this is where the Operating System comes into play. The PTE we got out of the page table existed, as in it was (let's assume) a valid memory address to access, but the OS had not created a VA->PA mapping for it yet, so it would have had a bit set to indicate that it is invalid. The hardware is programmed in such a way that when it sees this invalid bit upon an access, it generates an exception, in this case a page fault.

5) The exception causes the hardware to invoke the OS by jumping to a well known location--a piece of code called a handler. There can be many exception handlers, and a page fault handler is one of them. The page fault handler will know the address that caused the fault because it's stored in a register somewhere, and so will create a new mapping for our virtual address 0xDEADBEEF. It will do so by allocating a free page of physical memory and then saying "all virtual addresses between VA x and VA y will map to some address within this newly allocated page of physical memory". 0xDEADBEEF will be somewhere in that range, so the mapping is now securely in the page tables, and we can restart the instruction that caused the page fault (the mov).

6) Now, when we go through the page tables again, we will find a mapping and the PTE we pull out will have a nice physical address, the one we want to store to. We provide this with the value 10 to the memory controller and we're done!

Caches will change this game quite a bit, but I hope this serves to illustrate how paging works. Again, it would benefit you greatly to check out some OS/Computer Architecture books. I hope this was clear.

Comment: Want to add one more question. MMU is also responsible bus arbitration, right? How do you think it determines which core (or DMA-enabled device or DMA controller) should take over the address bus? And how it manages the contention on that bus?

Comment: MMUs are not involved in bus arbitration. Actually, current computer hardware does not use what I think of as buses -- they use point-to-point links arranged as a "network on chip" or "fabric" and arbitrating access to memory is implemented by the memory interconnect (network / fabric).

Comment: The register names in this answer belong to Intel CPUs. Other architectures have different names. See https://riscv.org/specifications/privileged-isa/ for the MMU spec for RISC-V. You can also download code for various RISC-V implementations to see how they are implemented.

Comment: How can MMU translate without the consultation with page table entry stored in RAM?

Answer (score 0):

There are data structures that describe which virtual addresses correspond to which physical addresses. The OS creates and manages these data structures, and the CPU uses them to translate virtual addresses into physical addresses.

For example, the OS might use these data structures to say "virtual addresses in the range from 0x00000000 to 0x00000FFF correspond to physical addresses 0x12340000 to 0x12340FFFF"; and if software tries to read 4 bytes from the virtual address 0x00000468 then the CPU will actually read 4 bytes from the physical address 0x12340468.

Typically everything is effected by the virtual->physical translation (except for when the CPU is accessing the data structures that describe the translation). Also, usually there's some sort of translation cache build into the CPU to help reduce the overhead involved.

Comment: Well, having in consideration the depth of the subject , talking about "some data structures that do this or that" is hardly of any help. I'd like a concrete example of what goes on at the OS and hardware level.

Comment: @devoured elysium: What CPU would you like to use for a concrete example?

Comment: basically, anything, as long as its descriptive and tells step by step what is actually happening. all articles on the web from the dinossaur book seem to skim over this part.