# Memory mapped IO - who maps the addresses to the physical address space?

Tags: operating-system, kernel, device-driver

When we say that a device is memory mapped,

1. Who maps the addresses to the devices?
2. How are these address spaces decided in terms of location and size?
3. Where are these maps stored?
4. Do these address spaces vary across system boots?

Comment: Are you interested in a specific operating system like Linux or Windows?

Comment: I am trying to get the general understanding of memory mapped IO. If you have a specific OS implementation, that'd be useful too!

Comment: Address decoding logic hardware handles the mapping.  The adresses and ranges may be configurable or fixed.  The exact mechanisms are architecture/OS dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly,

1. The MMU hardware.
2. The kernel manages the MMU tables used by the MMU hardware.
3. In a per-process structure. Under Linux, look at `/proc/<pid>/maps` to see all memory-mapped files and devices.
4. They can, so you should not count on them being fixed.

For further reading, I suggest the [Memory Mapping and DMA chapter](https://static.lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch15.pdf) from Linux Device Drivers, [this FAQ](http://landley.net/writing/memory-faq.txt), and [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812137/does-the-mmu-mediate-everything-between-the-operating-system-and-physical-memory).

Comment: Linux?  MMU?  Don't see them mentioned in the question.

Comment: @MartinJames: Absence of some terms in the question doesn't prohibit their usage in the answer.